# Apache beam for data validation, GCP

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I have a requirement to validate the incoming csv data against the metadata which is coming from a bigquery table. I am using dataflow in local to do this, but I am unable to find out a way how can I use apache beam transform to implement this logic.

Note: At the moment, I saw some code where ParDo was getting used in which sideinput is given. Is this a right approach?

Validation required: Before loading the data to a bigquery table I have to check it against the metadata, checking if it passes the validation. I have to insert the data to BQ table.

Sample code:

```
"Process Data into TableRows" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessDF(), 
                                 beam.pvalue.AsList(metadata_for_validation))
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "validate" and perhaps show some code that you have so far

Comment: before loading the data to a bigquery table I have to check it against the metadata, if it passed the validation, I have to insert the data to BQ table,

Comment: What issues are you having with looping over each CSV element then do a BiqQuery lookup or running your validation function?

Comment: Are you only looking to confirm that you're taking the right approach? If so, then yes I think this approach works. Making a ParDo that checks each input element and outputs only elements that pass the check would work. But in case it helps, there's a [Filter transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/filter/) already that seems to have the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks, for the updates, yes I was able to implement it using Pardo with values to be checked as side input, but I have use case where the file path for the input should read from the metadata which is present in one of column in metadata, any idea how this can be achieved, I tried to pass the output of Pcollection to ReadfromText, but it will only take string, and tried to convert the element of Pcollection using ToString, but no luck, any suggesions?